# Shared Controller Logic in Rails Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I've worked for several larger clients who have commissioned me to work on multiple rails apps at the same time.  Inevitably, this leads to them making one or more feature requests for one app that they expect to be moved to all of the apps, quickly.  E.g. A Feedback (email sending) web form.  Sharing models betweens apps is pretty straight forward, but sharing controllers and views in a gem/plugin tends to feel a bit wonky.

Are there any best practices that someone could recommend on how to share code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about packaging your shared code to one gem?

Comment: As I said, that is a possibility, but I don't see that happening a lot in the community. It also makes the code fairly hard to work with as the views/controller/routes would be hidden in a gem.  
 
If this is good practice, why wouldn't the community share user registration/sign in or such?

Comment: They do - The Devise Gem is a user signup and password management solution in a Gem.